# JS if else statements and timer

Tags: javascript, html

1)I have a problem with timer. It is starting when the screen loads, it should start on button START.
2)If else. When timer hits 00: 00 it should show message (alert) if i have won or lost. http://prntscr.com/ffi4bu wallvalue is constantly changing. My code is not working but you get the idea.

1)JS code timer

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration,minutes, seconds;
 var timers = setInterval(runner, 1000);
 function runner() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
       clearInterval(timers)
    }
  }

}

window.onload = function() {
  var oneMinutes = 60 * 1,
    display = document.querySelector('#time');
  startTimer(oneMinutes, display);
};
```

HTML

```
<div class="timer" ><b>Battle time: <span id="time"></span></b></div>
<BUTTON class="begin" onclick="startTimer(60,document.querySelector('#time'))"><b>START</b></BUTTON>
```

2) JS

```
function finish(){
    var g = function startTimer;
    var h = document.getElementById('wallvalue');

if (function startTimer = 0 )&& ( h<500 ) {
    alert("You won!");
}
 else {
 alert("You lost!");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st Remove your startTimer function call from window.onload if you want to call on button click. otherwise it will immediateload after window load.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var oneMinutes = 60 * 1,
  display = document.querySelector('#time');
  //startTimer(oneMinutes, display); 
};
```

Inside startTimer on "zero" value call finish and remove ambiguous function call lines from finish. Also just check "h" because "finsh" will be called when timer value is already zero.

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration,minutes, seconds;
  var timers = setInterval(runner, 1000);
  function runner() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (--timer <= 0) {
     clearInterval(timers)
     finish()
   }
 }

}



function finish(){

var h = document.getElementById('wallvalue');

if ( h<500 ) {
    alert("You won!");
}
 else {
 alert("You lost!");
}
}
```